# As a Kiwi living in Aus who may move back, how does one transfer super?

Tags: australia, new-zealand-citizens, retirement-funds

My understanding is a law change a few years back allows Kiwis and Aussies to transfer superannuation funds between the countries.

If I have Super in NZ, and now Super in Aus - if I move back to NZ, how do I go about transferring this Australian balance to my  NZ one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can indeed transfer retirement schemes from Australia to New Zealand.  The Australian Taxation Office has a page with details about the retirement savings portability scheme.

[Trans-Tasman retirement savings portability scheme for individuals - Transfers to New Zealand](https://www.ato.gov.au/Individuals/Super/In-detail/Withdrawing-and-paying-tax/Trans-Tasman-retirement-savings-portability-scheme-for-individuals/?anchor=Transfers_to_New_Zealand#Transfers_to_New_Zealand)

Points to note:

> - You may only transfer retirement savings between a complying APRA-regulated superannuation fund and a KiwiSaver scheme.
> - Check with your fund and KiwiSaver scheme to see if they will charge any fees for transferring or accepting funds on your behalf.
> - You will need a New Zealand Inland Revenue Department (IRD) number to transfer you retirement savings to a KiwiSaver scheme.

There is also a link from that page to apply for an IRD number if you don't already have one.

See also the NZ Inland Revenue Department fact-sheet:

[Fact sheet - Trans-Tasman portability of retirement savings - How the new rules work](http://taxpolicy.ird.govt.nz/publications/2013-other-trans-tasman-retirement-savings-portability/how-new-rules-work)